# React-Router: Nested route not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, nested-urls

This is a simplified reproduction of the problem: The child with the nested URL does not render.

My file structure is basically this:

```
-App
 --Home
 --Pageone
  ---Childone
```

I can render `Home` or `Pageone` from `App`, then I can render `Home` or `Pageone` from `Pageone` or `Home` respectively, but I cannot render `Childone` from its 'parent page' `Pageone`. I am not quite sure what is done wrong.

The code is shared below, and this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-pine-qgije?file=/src/App.jsx)

App.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Pageone from "./Pageone";
import Home from "./Home";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/pageone">
          <Pageone />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Home.jsx

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is HOME!</p>
      <Link to="/pageone">Pageone</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Pageone.jsx

```
import { Link, Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import Childone from "./Childone";

const Pageone = () => {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <Route exact path={path}>
        <PageoneContent url={url} />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path={path + "/childone"}>
        <Childone />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
};

const PageoneContent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is pageone!</p>
      <Link to="/">Go back Home</Link>
      <br />
      <Link to={props.url + "/childone"}>Go to Child One</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pageone;
```

Childone.jsx

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Childone = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is Child one!</p>
      <Link to="/">Go back Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Childone;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you need to use another `Switch` for routes, otherwise react will have no idea how to match that route path.

```
<div>
  <Route exact path={path}>
```

Should be:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={path}>
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. The `Childone` component still does not appear to render.

Comment: What I've given you is the answer, if it still isn't working then it's because you have the incorrect path or something.